# How to fix the width of <span> tag

Tags: css

i have a  tag inside of a  tag and i want that if there is a long text inside of  tag then that text should not go out side of div tag.
how to fix it.

```
<div width="100">
    <span>this is heading<br/>
        abcdefghi jk lmssdfd dfg fgfg gf gfgf gfg fgf hasasas asasasas sasasdfd  fdfdf
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you done, until now? Put in http://jsfiddle.net so we will be able to see your hierarchy

Answer (score 1):

Add `overflow:hidden` to the styling of the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 0):

Define width in proper style tag.

```
<div style="width:100px;">
    <span>this is heading<br/>
        abcdefghi jk lmssdfd dfg fgfg gf gfgf gfg fgf hasasas asasasas sasasdfd  fdfdf
    </span>
</div>
```

This will place the text inside the div only.

Answer (score 0):

The markup `<div width="100">` is invalid, and the `width` attribute is ignored by browsers in this context.

If you set a width for the element in a valid way, say `<div style="width: 100px">` (which is not good practice, as px dimensions should be avoided), then the content will stay within that width. However, if there is a word or other expression inside it that the browser cannot fit on one line within those limits, an overflow will occur, and it can be handled in different ways. The question does not specify whether this is the problem and what kind of solution is desired then (e.g., should the contents be truncated?).